# ¿Cómo cargar una lista anidada desde Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

tengo un problema y es que quiero cargar en un recyclerview una lista de pedidos que contiene otra lista anidada cada uno, es una aplicación de pedidos y la he estructurado de la siguiente manera en Firebase

```
"Pedidos" : {
//Aquí el Uid de cada usuario
"1pkGJtMl5vMzFx8hSkLWKHzic4y1" : {
  //Aquí el key de cada pedido
  "-KvjkZG9-o785U5FF-Ij" : {
    //Esta es la lista de items que pide
    "items" : {
      "hamburguesa" : "true",
      "perro" : "true"
    },
    //Aquí el Uid de la persona que pide
    "solicitante" : "3sZACUy3zsbvmpUrU2SSqeIqga43"
  }
}
```

luego tengo mi firebase recycler adapter, y he logrado cargar el id del solicitante pero no se como cargar los items del pedido, he leido que no se usa una List<> sino un map<> pero no puedo lograrlo.

este es mi recycler adapter

```
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Pedido, ViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Pedido, ViewHolder>(

            Pedido.class,
            R.layout.single_pedido,
            ViewHolder.class,
            mPedidoDatabase
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, final Pedido model, int position) {

            final String list_rest_id  = getRef(position).getKey();



        }
    };

    mListaPedidos.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
```

este es el objeto pedido pero solo tiene el atributo solicitante

```
public class Pedido  {

String solicitante;

public Pedido(String solicitante) {
    this.solicitante= solicitante;

}

public Pedido() {
}

public String getsolicitante() {
    return solicitante;
}

public void setsolicitante(String solicitante) {
    this.solicitante= solicitante;
}
```

¿Cómo puedo cargar esa lista de items anidada en cada pedido? por favor ayuda, y anticipo agradecimientos.